# Dockerfile not found on ubuntu 16.04, dockerfile exists

Tags: docker

I have docker-compose.yml with the following lines

```
nginx:
build:
context: ./containers/nginx
dockerfile: ./containers/nginx/Dockerfile.dev
```

And when I try to do docker-compose up -d nginx it returns me a error

```
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: ./containers/nginx/Dockerfile.dev
```

The Dockerfile.dev exists in that directory.

Comment: Yml files are white space sensitive. Please update your question to include the rest of the yml file, including the version line, and white space in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I thought context specified the directory of your docker file so docker file shouldn't include a path.

```
nginx:
build:
context: ./containers/nginx
dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
```